# Conditional format rules are not working in google sheets. it works on 2 condition if add 3rd it will not work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

What I want to do here.

1. If cell "AA" is >= 10 whole row is red: This is working
2. If cell "AA" is >= 7 whole row is orange: This is working
3. If cell "V" is = "Order Cancelled" it will override the above 2 conditions and the whole row will be green: This is now working.
4. If cell "V" is = "Shipped" it will override all and the whole row will be blue: now this is not working
   P.N: I have no problem doing the same in MS Excel, But Google Sheets giving me headaches.

[image: My sample sheet]
[Problem is now here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmNJ7.jpg)

Comment: Could you share a copy of the sheet publicly to test the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just move the green one above the red one. on the left next to the color box there are 3 dots. grab them and move it up

Comment: Thank you,But now i want to =$V2="Shipped" to be green or any color. is not working